# Transform Expression m => m.Name to m => m[index].Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, lambda, expression

Given an `Expression<Func<T, TValue>>` (like `m => m.Name`) and an `index`, I'd like to be able to transform my expression to `m => m[index].Name`). And I must admit I'm stuck...

I give you the actual scenario if you want the "Why the hell" (and maybe find a better way).

Scenario : imagine a **Server Side Editable Grid** (*without javascript*).

I build my grid with an helper which look like that :

```
@(Html.Grid(Model)
.Columns(columns => {
   columns.Edit(m => m.Name);
   columns.Edit(m => m.Code);
})
.AsEditable());
```

Model is an `IQueryable<T>`

`m => m.Name` is an `Expression<Func<T, TValue>>` (`TValue` is string)

`m => m.Code` is an `Expression<Func<T, TValue>>` (`TValue` is int)

When rendering my view, I'd like to display an html form. 
The `IQueryable<T>` is enumerated (order, pagination). => ok

So I'll have a `List<T>` of 5, 10 or 20 `T` items.

And `Name` and `Code` should be represented as `TextBox`, using a classic `HtmlHelper.TextBoxFor(Expression<Func<T, TValue>>)`  (no problem to create the `HtmlHelper<T>`)

But as I've got a list, if I want correct Model binding, I can't use directly `m => m.Name`, but should use `m => m[indexOfItem in List<T>].Name`

**Edit** : more details :

So let's say we have an entity class

```
public class Test {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Code {get;set;}
}
```

Then, a method retrieving an `IQueryable<Test>`

Then a view

```
@model IQueryable<Test>

@(Html.Grid(Model)
    .Columns(columns => {
       columns.Edit(m => m.Name);
       columns.Edit(m => m.Code);
    })
    .AsEditable());
```

as you see, Model given as parameter is `IQueryable<Test>`.

```
m => m.Name
```

and

```
m => m.Code
```

are just properties of the Model (which I wanna display as TextBox in my grid).

The model is an `IQueryable<T>` (not an `IEnumerable<T>`), because the Grid manages ordering and Pagination, so that my controller and service layer don't need to know about pagination and ordering.

Is it clearer ?

Comment: The lambda approach you are using is correct. In view enumerate over the elements and render the text boxes. Where do you want to "get" the `indexOfItem`?

Comment: When calling HtmlHelper.TextBoxFor for each row of my grid. If I use Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code), It will generate `<input type="text" name="Code" id="Code" value="blabla">`. But I need a distinct id and name for each row, or my model binding will fail (The Post action should get a `List<T>` as parameter. I could create the `input` manually, but was looking for a more elegant way...

Comment: If you have the index, why don't you directly write `columns.Edit(m => m[index].Name);`? Actually question is wrong. You cannot transform `m => m.Name` into `m => m[index].Name` simply because `m` in this context is not a collection. So I guess you need a different transformation but I don't quite understand which.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Well, I don't have the index when calling my helper in my view... I can find the index during rendering (after I enumerated the IQueryable, and generate my rows)

Comment: Alright, let's suppose that we could write such method to transform the expression. Could you show how do you expect to use it in your view?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov well, sorry if I'm not clear, but as shown in example it's the `@Html.Grid` helper (Nothing really different from similar helpers, like Telerik or Mvc contrib's ones in the principle, if you know them, and already have a Display part working fine : but I  need that "editable list" part)

Comment: But in your example the columns are hardcoded. So you want to extend the grid? Also grids such as MvcContrib are normally bound to `IEnumerable<T>` models but in your example you are using `m => m.Name` which is wrong if your `Model` is `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov My edit should make (hope so) things clearer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be easily achieved by writing a custom [ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx):

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    private class Visitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly int _index;
        public Visitor(int index)
        {
            _index = index;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return Expression.ArrayIndex(GetArrayParameter(node), Expression.Constant(_index));
        }

        public ParameterExpression GetArrayParameter(ParameterExpression parameter)
        {
            var arrayType = parameter.Type.MakeArrayType();
            return Expression.Parameter(arrayType, parameter.Name);
        }
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T[], TValue>> BuildArrayFromExpression<T, TValue>(
        this Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expression,
        int index
    )
    {
        var visitor = new Visitor(index);
        var nexExpression = visitor.Visit(expression.Body);
        var parameter = visitor.GetArrayParameter(expression.Parameters.Single());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T[], TValue>>(nexExpression, parameter);
    }
}
```

and then you could use this extension method like this:

```
Expression<Func<Test, string>> ex = m => m.Code;
Expression<Func<Test[], string>> newEx = ex.BuildArrayFromExpression(1);
```

Comment: Well, after (quite) a while on far far away projects, I tried to use your code in a real scenario : while using the resulting expression (something like m => m[0].MyItem) as parameter of an `HtmlHelper.DropDownListFor` it's working fine. But using it on an `HtmlHelper.TextBoxFor`, I get the (annoying) `variable m of type MyItem is referenced from scope, but it is not defined` message. Knowing that the code given in my (ugly) answer works, do you have an idea ? I will search also, but I didn't work much on expression visitors...

Comment: Well, got a solution by adding a public property of type ParameterExpression, and instanciating it in GetArrayParameter method... Not that clean, but got the idea, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Well, got something (ugly, just for testing purpose) working, but it makes things unclear, so I'll wait for a better solution or build my input another way :

```
public static Expression<Func<T[], TValue>> BuildArrayFromExpression<T, TValue>(this Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expression, int index)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T[]), "m");
    Expression body = Expression.ArrayIndex(parameter, Expression.Constant(index));
    var type = typeof(T);
    var properties = expression.Body.ToString().Split('.');//ugly shortcut for test only
    foreach (var property in properties.Skip(1))
    {
        var pi = type.GetProperty(property);
        body = Expression.Property(body, type.GetProperty(property));
        type = pi.PropertyType;
    }
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T[], TValue>>(body, parameter);
}
```

used in a RenderMethod, called for each line of my `List<T>` (the paginated /ordered list returned from my `IQueryable<T>`)

```
public override ... RenderContent(T dataItem) {
  var helper = new HtmlHelper<T[]>(GridModel.Context, new GridViewDataContainer<T[]>(GridModel.PaginatedItems.ToArray(), GridModel.Context.ViewData));
  var modifiedExpression = Expression.BuildArrayFromExpression(GridModel.PaginatedItems.IndexOf(dataItem));//GridModel.PaginatedItems is the List<T> returned when "executing" the IQueryable<T>
  var textBox = helper.TextBoxFor(modifiedExpression);
  ...
}
```